# How to deal with overhydration?

Tags: home-remedies, hydration

I have been told by a gym trainer, that I am quite possibly overhydrated. Are there any home remedies for this?

Answer (score 1):

[Treatment](http://www.merckmanuals.com/home/hormonal-and-metabolic-disorders/water-balance/overhydration) is usually fluid restriction, treating underlying problem and diuretics or other medication for fluid and electrolyte imbalance, so you could do a fluid restriction at home. However, the causes of overhydration usually are renal, heart or liver problems, hormonal disorders and increased fluid intake. So you can't just treat all that, when your unsure of the diagnosis. That said it is also known as water poisoning and water intoxication for a reason. [Symptoms](http://www.healthline.com/health/overhydration#Diagnosis5) can be:

Mild:

> nausea and vomiting headache changes in mental state (confusion or
>   disorientation)

Or severe:

> muscle weakness, spasms or cramps seizures, unconsciousness,  coma

If severe symptoms occur and the overhydration is caused by a underlying condition you will need to see a doctor. It is best to see a doctor right off if you suspect anything, because diagnosis comes from urine and blood test, physical examination and patient history. Also, the treatment for a underlying condition may need more care than you can receive at home.